# jQuery validate: How to add a rule for regular expression validation?

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I am using the **[jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) validation plugin**. Great stuff! I want to migrate my existing ASP.NET solution to use jQuery instead of the ASP.NET validators. I am missing a replacement for the **regular expression** validator. I want to be able to do something like this:

```
$("Textbox").rules("add", { regularExpression: "^[a-zA-Z'.\s]{1,40}$" })
```

How do I **add a custom rule** to achieve this?

Comment: Please say you're checking the input server side and not just relying on client side validation as this can obviously be turned off.

Comment: of course! :-) Validation on the server is a must

Comment: OMG it **DOESN'T** have regex validation?!

Comment: I mean, who'd want regex for validation anyway...  ... ;)

Answer (score 355, accepted):

Thanks to the answer of redsquare I added a method like this:

```js
$.validator.addMethod(
  "regex",
  function(value, element, regexp) {
    var re = new RegExp(regexp);
    return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
  },
  "Please check your input."
);
```

Now all you need to do to validate against any regex is this:

```js
$("#Textbox").rules("add", { regex: "^[a-zA-Z'.\\s]{1,40}$" })
```

Additionally, it looks like there is a file called `additional-methods.js` that contains the method "pattern", which can be a `RegExp` when created using the method without quotes.

---

### Edit

The `pattern` function is now the preferred way to do this, making the example:

```js
$("#Textbox").rules("add", { pattern: "^[a-zA-Z'.\\s]{1,40}$" })
```

- https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-validate

  - https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.2/jquery.validate.min.js
  - https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.2/additional-methods.min.js

Comment: What is the point of the unused variable assignment "var check = false;"?  "check" is not checked anywhere, pun intended.

Comment: $("Textbox") should be $("#Textbox").

Comment: I would have let the RegExp be defined outside the method as a literal, instead of the invocation from a string..

Comment: this is super useful and should be included in jquery :(

Comment: @RyanShripat: I added `#` to the selector, also I removed unused `check` variable.

Comment: I want regular expression validation in add form of JQgrid. How can I do that ?

Comment: @Bhavik Ambani ask a question with a new stackoverflow question not a comment

Comment: You can also call it inline with the following syntax: <input type="text" name="entryCode" regex="[abc]+" />  Great job!

Comment: Or add it to validator like this: ... rules: { textbox_input_name_attr: {
   required: true,
   regex: "^[a-zA-Z'.\\s]{1,50}$"
  } }, ....

Comment: thank you for answer, only thing is that for e it worked when i put regular expression in slashes, not quotes

Comment: you should add message to the function parameters so you can pass a custom message too...

Comment: abc123 how would you enter a custom message?

Comment: You enter a custom message like this: $('#element').rules('add', { regex: /[abc]/, messages { regex: "custom message' }});

Comment: I am trying to implement the following regex to my jqueryui validate  ^(\d+(?:(?: \d+)*\/\d+)?)$  .. it works on regex tester http://regex101.com/r/cB3fQ1/2 but not when I put it into the validate structure as regex: "^(\d+(?:(?: \d+)*\/\d+)?)$" ... can anyone advise? @naspinski

Answer (score 85):

You can use the addMethod()

e.g

```
$.validator.addMethod('postalCode', function (value) { 
    return /^((\d{5}-\d{4})|(\d{5})|([A-Z]\d[A-Z]\s\d[A-Z]\d))$/.test(value); 
}, 'Please enter a valid US or Canadian postal code.');
```

good article here https://web.archive.org/web/20130609222116/http://www.randallmorey.com/blog/2008/mar/16/extending-jquery-form-validation-plugin/

Comment: Don't really answer the question. What if you want a general regex rule?
With this answer you would have to addMethod for each diffrent regex.

Answer (score 45):

I had some trouble putting together all the pieces for doing a jQuery regular expression validator, but I got it to work... Here is a complete working example. It uses the 'Validation' plugin which can be found in *[jQuery Validation Plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)*

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script src="http://YOURJQUERYPATH/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://YOURJQUERYPATH/js/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $().ready(function() {
            $.validator.addMethod("EMAIL", function(value, element) {
                return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z.]{2,5}$/i.test(value);
            }, "Email Address is invalid: Please enter a valid email address.");

            $.validator.addMethod("PASSWORD",function(value,element){
                return this.optional(element) || /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,16}$/i.test(value);
            },"Passwords are 8-16 characters with uppercase letters, lowercase letters and at least one number.");

            $.validator.addMethod("SUBMIT",function(value,element){
                return this.optional(element) || /[^ ]/i.test(value);
            },"You did not click the submit button.");

            // Validate signup form on keyup and submit
            $("#LOGIN").validate({
                rules: {
                    EMAIL: "required EMAIL",
                    PASSWORD: "required PASSWORD",
                    SUBMIT: "required SUBMIT",
                },
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="LOGIN_FORM" class="form">
        <form id="LOGIN" name="LOGIN" method="post" action="/index/secure/authentication?action=login">
            <h1>Log In</h1>
            <div id="LOGIN_EMAIL">
                <label for="EMAIL">Email Address</label>
                <input id="EMAIL" name="EMAIL" type="text" value="" tabindex="1" />
            </div>
            <div id="LOGIN_PASSWORD">
                <label for="PASSWORD">Password</label>
                <input id="PASSWORD" name="PASSWORD" type="password" value="" tabindex="2" />
            </div>
            <div id="LOGIN_SUBMIT">
                <input id="SUBMIT" name="SUBMIT" type="submit" value="Submit" tabindex="3" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 27):

No reason to define the regex as a string.

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    "regex",
    function(value, element, regexp) {
        var check = false;
        return this.optional(element) || regexp.test(value);
    },
    "Please check your input."
);
```

and

```
telephone: { required: true, regex : /^[\d\s]+$/, minlength: 5 },
```

tis better this way, no?

Comment: which js is required for this ?

Comment: Actually, just found an issue with this. If you use the g flag you will get inconsistent results. The g flag creates it's own index apparently (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209732/why-am-i-seeing-inconsistent-javascript-logic-behavior-looping-with-an-alert-v). So you need to redefine the regex IN the function so it's recreated each time it is called.

Comment: To add to that: still define it as a regex, as above (or you'll have issues with string > regex conversion with flags ) BUT in addition it still needs the `var re = new RegExp(regexp);` in the function

Answer (score 25):

Extending PeterTheNiceGuy's answer a bit:

```
$.validator.addMethod(
        "regex",
        function(value, element, regexp) {
            if (regexp.constructor != RegExp)
                regexp = new RegExp(regexp);
            else if (regexp.global)
                regexp.lastIndex = 0;
            return this.optional(element) || regexp.test(value);
        },
        "Please check your input."
);
```

This would allow you to pass a regex object to the rule.

```
$("Textbox").rules("add", { regex: /^[a-zA-Z'.\s]{1,40}$/ });
```

Resetting the `lastIndex` property is necessary when the `g`-flag is set on the `RegExp` object. Otherwise it would start validating from the position of the last match with that regex, even if the subject string is different.

Some other ideas I had was be to enable you use arrays of regex's, and another rule for the negation of regex's:

```
$("password").rules("add", {
    regex: [
        /^[a-zA-Z'.\s]{8,40}$/,
        /^.*[a-z].*$/,
        /^.*[A-Z].*$/,
        /^.*[0-9].*$/
    ],
    '!regex': /password|123/
});
```

But implementing those would maybe be too much.

Comment: I want regular expression validation in add form of JQgrid. How can I do that ?

Comment: @BhavikAmbani You can use a custom function for validation. See [the wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editrules) for an example.

Answer (score 19):

As mentioned on the [addMethod documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod):

Please note: While the temptation is great to add a regex method that checks it's parameter against the value, it is much cleaner to encapsulate those regular expressions inside their own method. If you need lots of slightly different expressions, try to extract a common parameter. A library of regular expressions: http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx

So yes, you have to add a method for each regular expression. The overhead is minimal, while it allows you to give the regex a name (not to be underestimated), a default message (handy) and the ability to reuse it a various places, without duplicating the regex itself over and over.

Comment: Your answer is much apreciated! Thanks. I will think about it again. In our case the Regex validation seemed to be the best fit. However I understand your point in using "named" validations...

Answer (score 18):

I got it to work like this:

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    "regex",
    function(value, element, regexp) {
        return this.optional(element) || regexp.test(value);
    },
    "Please check your input."
);


$(function () {
    $('#uiEmailAdress').focus();
    $('#NewsletterForm').validate({
        rules: {
            uiEmailAdress:{
                required: true,
                email: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            uiConfirmEmailAdress:{
                required: true,
                email: true,
                equalTo: '#uiEmailAdress'
            },
            DDLanguage:{
                required: true
            },
            Testveld:{
                required: true,
                regex: /^[0-9]{3}$/
            }
        },
        messages: {
            uiEmailAdress:{
                required: 'Verplicht veld',
                email: 'Ongeldig emailadres',
                minlength: 'Minimum 5 charaters vereist'
            },
            uiConfirmEmailAdress:{
                required: 'Verplicht veld',
                email: 'Ongeldig emailadres',
                equalTo: 'Veld is niet gelijk aan E-mailadres'
            },
            DDLanguage:{
                required: 'Verplicht veld'
            },
            Testveld:{
                required: 'Verplicht veld',
                regex: '_REGEX'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Make sure that the regex is between `/` :-)

Answer (score 16):

You may use *`pattern`* defined in the *`additional-methods.js`* file. Note that this additional-methods.js file must be included *after* jQuery Validate dependency, then you can just use

```js
$("#frm").validate({
    rules: {
        Textbox: {
            pattern: /^[a-zA-Z'.\s]{1,40}$/
        },
    },
    messages: {
        Textbox: {
            pattern: 'The Textbox string format is invalid'
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<form id="frm" method="get" action="">
    <fieldset>
        <p>
            <label for="fullname">Textbox</label>
            <input id="Textbox" name="Textbox" type="text">
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 5):

This is working code.

```
function validateSignup()
{   
    $.validator.addMethod(
            "regex",
            function(value, element, regexp) 
            {
                if (regexp.constructor != RegExp)
                    regexp = new RegExp(regexp);
                else if (regexp.global)
                    regexp.lastIndex = 0;
                return this.optional(element) || regexp.test(value);
            },
            "Please check your input."
    );

    $('#signupForm').validate(
    {

        onkeyup : false,
        errorClass: "req_mess",
        ignore: ":hidden",
        validClass: "signup_valid_class",
        errorClass: "signup_error_class",

        rules:
        {

            email:
            {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                regex: /^[A-Za-z0-9_]+\@[A-Za-z0-9_]+\.[A-Za-z0-9_]+/,
            },

            userId:
            {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6,
                maxlength: 15,
                regex: /^[A-Za-z0-9_]{6,15}$/,
            },

            phoneNum:
            {
                required: true,
                regex: /^[+-]{1}[0-9]{1,3}\-[0-9]{10}$/,
            },

        },
        messages: 
        {
            email: 
            {
                required: 'You must enter a email',
                regex: 'Please enter a valid email without spacial chars, ie, Example@gmail.com'
            },

            userId:
            {
                required: 'Alphanumeric, _, min:6, max:15',
                regex: "Please enter any alphaNumeric char of length between 6-15, ie, sbp_arun_2016"
            },

            phoneNum: 
            {
                required: "Please enter your phone number",
                regex: "e.g. +91-1234567890"    
            },

        },

        submitHandler: function (form)
        {
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

we mainly use the markup notation of jquery validation plugin and the posted samples did not work for us, when flags are present in the regex, e.g.

```
<input type="text" name="myfield" regex="/^[0-9]{3}$/i" />
```

therefore we use the following snippet

```
$.validator.addMethod(
        "regex",
        function(value, element, regstring) {
            // fast exit on empty optional
            if (this.optional(element)) {
                return true;
            }

            var regParts = regstring.match(/^\/(.*?)\/([gim]*)$/);
            if (regParts) {
                // the parsed pattern had delimiters and modifiers. handle them. 
                var regexp = new RegExp(regParts[1], regParts[2]);
            } else {
                // we got pattern string without delimiters
                var regexp = new RegExp(regstring);
            }

            return regexp.test(value);
        },
        "Please check your input."
);
```

Of course now one could combine this code, with one of the above to also allow passing RegExp objects into the plugin, but since we didn't needed it we left this exercise for the reader ;-).

PS: there is also bundled plugin for that, https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/src/additional/pattern.js

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, being one of the validation rules:

```
    Zip: {
                required: true,
                regex: /^\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?$/
            }
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

```
    $.validator.methods.checkEmail = function( value, element ) {
        return this.optional( element ) || /[a-z]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z]+/.test( value );
    }

    $("#myForm").validate({
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                checkEmail: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            email: "incorrect email"
        }
    });
```

Comment: You can add a specific message to the custom validator like so
```$.validator.messages.checkEmail = "Invalid email";```