# How to remove space and restrict special chars using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I am creating a signup form in my website. I want to implement some checkup with username, which are

- username can't have any space,
- username can't have any special characters other than dot (.) as gmail is doing in thier signup form.

I am using jQUERY in my app, can anyone tell me how to implement above listed two checkups using jquery ?? I remember these two main checkups for username please suggest if you knows any other?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried out following jquery script by studying the links ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280759/jquery-validate-how-to-add-a-rule-for-regular-expression-validation)) given by @Dror to check for wrong characters in username,

```
if (!$('#uname').val().match("^[a-z0-9'.\s]{1,50}$")) {
    //not a correct username
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [validation plug-in](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).

Whatever you do, validate the username at the server side too.

Comment: Very good point - you shouldn't rely solely on client side validation as it can easily be by-passed +1.

Answer (score 3):

You can check that using javascript regex:

```
if ($('#username').val().match(/^(\w)+[\w\d\.]*/)) {
  // everyting is ok
}else {
  // something is wrong
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First see here in another entry in SO, [jquery-validate-how-to-add-a-rule-for-regular-expression-validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280759/jquery-validate-how-to-add-a-rule-for-regular-expression-validation).

if you need other ideas try [here](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/using-ajax-to-validate-forms/) for an example using PHP and an AJAX call using jQuery.

You can also check out [this](http://www.willjessup.com/sandbox/jquery/form_validator/form_validate.html) page for a another jQuery solution.

Answer (score 0):

When I checked the answers, I saw that space is allowed. So I improve the regex for others that will read this question:

You need to do like this:

```
if (!$('#uname').val().match(/^[a-z0-9_-]{3,15}$/)) {
    alert("Please, use standard characters.");
}
```

Description of regex:

> ^ -- Start of the line
>
> [a-z0-9_-] -- Match characters and symbols in the list, a-z, 0-9,
>   underscore, hyphen
>
> {3,15} -- Length at least 3 characters and maximum length of 15
>
> $ -- End of the line