# Handling error messages using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, validation

I've an asp.net page having a server side submit button and 2 textboxes which accept only numeric values.Am also using asp.net validation controls.

If the user types in non-numeric data in both the textboxes, how do i show only 1 error message on the page saying:
"Only numeric values are allowed."
And I want to achieve this without firing a server side event.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well obviously you'll need to do this with javascript.

I don't know the exact javascript methods to check if input is numeric, I'm guessing you can use a regex.  But you could have a hidden div such as

```
<div id="numericErrorMessage" class="error" style="display:none;">
        Numeric Values only.
</div>
```

Then you can do:

```
if(!IsNumber(text1)  || !IsNumber(text2)) {
   document.getElementById(numericErrorMesage).style.display = 'block';
}
```

of course this is "pseudocodish" but I think this will work for you once you find the way javascript can check for valid numbers and just place that in the IsNumber function

Comment: thanks...will this soln work across safari,firefox,ie browsers?

Comment: I'm guessing it would, doc.getelemntbyid is pretty standard.

Answer (score 1):

You could use jquery validation using the \d regex above.  Using jquery you will have more control of the output.  [It is discussed here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280759/jquery-validate-how-to-add-a-rule-for-regular-expression-validation)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Regex Validator:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="RegularExpressionValidator1" 
                 ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
                 ValidationExpression="\d"
                 Display="Static"
                 ErrorMessage="Only numeric values are allowed."
                 EnableClientScript="True" 
                 runat="server"/>
```

Comment: thanks...but if i attach RegularExpressionValidator to each of the textboxes and if user types in non numeric values in both of them, then the error message would be shown twice which I dont want to show on the page.I want to show error message only once.

Comment: You're right. I have upvoted Jack's answers since his satisfies the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a custom validator if you only want one error message.  You will have to write your own server and client validation functions, but that is easy enough.  Here is a link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5db6z8k(VS.71).aspx

You could also use a compare validator, but then you are going to have to have one for each control, and you will cause two error messages.