# Charset validation in web text field

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, validation, character-encoding

I need to limit character input in a text field (using ASP.Net/JavaScript/JQuery) to only allow characters in the ISO/IEC 8859-1 charset.

How would I do this?

Comment: What have you tried? You should check the data both server-side and client-side. You should also consider whether you really need to restrict data to ISO 8859-1 and not to windows-1252.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the charset of the page to `ISO-8859-1` using `<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">` then use a regexp like the following `[\x20-\x7E\xA0-\xFF]`. The regex will match any visible characters from  `ISO-8859-1`

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547669/restricting-text-box-inputs-to-a-given-regexp-using-jquery) answer shows how to restrict input based on regex.