# Using JQuery Validation Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I was wondering if someone could help me using the JQuery validation plugin.  I need to add the ability to make sure that a field only contains letters, numbers, underscores, whitespacke, and dashes.  I currently have the following js code (not including the call to jquery and the plugin .js files)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#info_frm").validate();

});

function submitForm() {
    if( $("#info_frm").valid() ) {
        document.info_frm.submit();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a regex method to validate your field:

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    "namecheck", function(value) {
        return /^[-_\sa-zA-Z0-9]*$/.test(value);
    }, "This name is not correct"
);
```

now you can add the rule:

```
$("[name='yourfieldname']").rules("add", { namecheck: true })
```

or

```
<input type="text" class="required namecheck" name="yourfieldname" />
```

Comment: FYI: ("yourfieldname").rules("add", { namecheck: true }) lacks $ in it... should have been $("yourfieldname").rules("add", { namecheck: true })

Comment: moreover, $("yourfieldname") is not a valid selector. it is def not a name selector

Answer (score 2):

you could add a method depending on the what rules you want. for example:

```
$.validator.addMethod(
        "numeric", 
        function(value, element) {
            var regex=/^[0-9]+$/; //this is for numeric... you can do any regular expression you like...
            return this.optional(element) || regex.test(value);
        },
        "Only numeric please."
);
```

Try looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280759/jquery-validate-how-to-add-a-rule-for-regular-expression-validation/709358#709358) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

check out my validation plugin, it allows for the following:

- Required Field Validation
- Regular Expression Validation
- Email Validation
- Numeric Validation
- Conditional Validation

You can [check it out here](http://jeremy.infinicastonline.com/2010/01/jquery-validator/).

**REMEMBER** Client side validation isn't enough.  You must also validate on the server.