# How to use regex to check that user input does not consist of special characters only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

How to put a validation over a field which wouldn't allow only special characters, that means `AB#,A89@,@#ASD` is allowed but `@#$^&` or `#` is not allowed. I need the RegEx for this validation.

Comment: this has nothing to do with jQuery, you mean javascript ?

Comment: Nono... JavaScript has been renamed to jQuery, didntchya know?

Comment: @OP: You might want to take a look at http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280759/jquery-validate-how-to-add-a-rule-for-regular-expression-validation

Answer (score 10):

```
str.match(/^[A-Z#@,]+$/)
```

will match a string that...

- ... starts `^` and ends `$` with the enclosed pattern
- ... contains any upper case letters `A-Z` (will not match lower case letters)
- ... contains only the special chars `#`, `@`, and `,`
- ... has at least 1 character (no empty string)

For case insensitive, you can add `i` at the end : (i.g. `/pattern/i`)

** **UPDATE** **

If you need to validate if the field contains only specials characters, you can check if the string contains only characters that are not words or numbers :

```
if (str.match(/^[^A-Z0-9]*$/i)) {
   alert('Invalid');
} else {
   alert('Valid');
}
```

This will match a string which contains only non-alphanumeric characters. An empty string will also yield invalid. Replace `*` with `+` to allow empty strings to be valid.

Comment: i think i did'nt make you understand,point is there are too many of special characters & what i wrote earlier are just the instances["AB#,A89@,@#ASD is allowed but @#$^& or # is not allowed"].It can be of any combination like A*B,AB*,*Ab but there should'nt be only special characters.The only way to use special character on that particular field is to associate the special charater with either Digit[e.g-9()] or with any character.whta to do??

Answer (score 2):

If you can use a "negative match" for your validation, i. e. the input is OK if the regex does *not* match, then I suggest

```
^\W*$
```

This will match a string that consists only of non-word characters (or the empty string).

If you need a positive match, then use

```
^\W*\w.*$
```

This will match if there is at least one alphanumeric character in the string.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is something like this:

```
!str.match(/^[@#$^&]*$/)
```

Checks that the string does *not* contain *only* symbols, i.e., it contains at least one character that *isn't* a symbol.