# Required field validators in jquery

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I want to give validation in my form fields..

**Fields:**

1. ***Name (textbox)*** --> Should enter the value. When without enter & come out it will show error message.
2. ***Email(regex)*** -->checking the mail format
3. ***Gender(radio button)*** -->any one radio button should selected
4. ***Location(dropdown)*** --> without enter dropdown will show error message
5. ***Mobile Number(textbox)*** --> enter only numbers

The above all types of validation I need.

```
$('#Email').click(function(){
            var name=$('#Name').val();
            if(name==""){
                $('#Name').after('<div class="red">Name is Required</div>');

            }
            });
```

But whenever i click email box it shows error message.How to do it? Please Help me? I tried 1 st field **Name**

Comment: hey you are doing the click fucntino for email, but has the check for #Name, Is this you required. if so, This may be happening
1. Name field is empty,
2. Now when you click on #Email field, then #Name field is validating.
Why can't you use jquery.validator.js plugin, it will suit your needs.

Comment: Search for blur(),selectedIndexChanded() events and  email regex `/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/` and search how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't supposed to do it on the `click` event of the **email** textbox, but on the `blur` event of the **name** textbox. The blur event is fired whenever a control loses focus. Try this,

```
$("#Name").blur(function(){
    if($(this).val().length === 0){
        $(this).after('<div class="red">Name is Required</div>');
    }
});
```

Here I am checking the length of the value inside the `#Name` textbox, whenever it **loses focus**. Now when you are submitting your form, you'll have to make this check again when the user presses the button click event.

Similarly to validate the email field, you'll use the regex that @onlyVJ gave.

`/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/`

You'll get the value from the textbox and match it with the regex, using match. [Follow this link to learn more.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649583/regex-in-jquery) This will be done on the `blur` event of the **#Email** textbox

**EDITED** -

I won't be giving you code but, I'll be instructing you on an approach that you can use.

For *dropdown* -

You can attach a blur event to dropdown, and check the whether the default value that you show in the beginning when the page loads is still the selected value. If so, show the error, else don't.

For *radio buttons* -

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/54y69/217/). Grabbed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5745104/903324). You should be able to use that to configure your code to display error when radio button is not checked.

Comment: can u instruct me dropdown and radiobuttons also?

Comment: Didn't work so I used `$(this).val()` instead of `this.val()`

Comment: @Fanky - Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the blur event to identify that an element has lost focus. Visit the [documentation for blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) for more information and an example.

If you want you could also try the jQuery validation plugin. Visit the [jQuery Validation Plugin website](http://jqueryvalidation.org)

Answer (score 0):

something like this...

```
$("#element").blur(function(){
   $(this).validate({
      // your code here
   })
})
```