# jQuery validate plugin: Value in multiple ranges

Tags: jquery, error-handling, validation

I use the jQuery Validate plugin to validate a form, and I want a value to be either below 26 or above 30. How can I do this?

I tried:

```
forum_id: { required: true, range: [0,26], range:[40,100] }
```

but then it just takes the last range, so if the value is below 40, it throws an error even if it's below 26 too.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a way to do this using the plug-in itself, but several people have suggested using a regular expression to validate ranges.

This resource demonstrates how to add a regex method to the validator:

[jQuery validate: How to add a rule for regular expression validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280759/jquery-validate-how-to-add-a-rule-for-regular-expression-validation)

I also took this a step further and wrote a plug-in to handle multiple ranges:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

 $.validator.addMethod(
    "ranges",
     function(value, element, ranges) {
        var noUpperBound = false;
        var valid = false;
        for(var i=0; i<ranges.length; i++) {
            if(ranges[i].length == 1) { 
                noUpperBound = true;
            }
            if(value >= ranges[i][0] && (value <= ranges[i][1] || noUpperBound)) {
                valid = true;
                break;
            }            
        }

        return this.optional(element) || valid;
    },
    "Please check your input."
 );


 $("#myform").validate({
     submitHandler: function(form) {
        if(form && form.submit) form.submit();
     } 
 });

 // range must be between 0 to 25 OR greater than 30
   // represented as an array of size-2 arrays.
 $("#age").rules('add', { ranges: [ [0,25], [31] ] });


 <form id="myform" action="#">
    <span>age</span><input type="text" id="age" name="age" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
 </form>
```