# jquery validate plugin - How avoid from user insert white-spaces in input

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How avoid from user insert white-spaces in  ?
(I use jquery.validate.js plugin)

Example:

input not possible(because user not able insert white-spaces): **John Pitt My**

input possible:**JohnPittMy**

**Edit:**

1. use of regex in this case mistake - should be used only value.indexOf(' ')
2. please I asking how to that with only http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Thanks

Comment: with the indexof there is a problem that the keydown is called when the key is pressed so you cant check that the .value contains a bad char or not, and if you trying to check with the keyup event, you cant interrupt the key pressing.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(value.match(/^([^\s])*$/)) {return true;}
```

hope this good.not tested. mut mainly you should use regular expression.

preventing insert spaces:

```
$("#username").keypress(function(e) {
     if(e.which == 32) {
        e.preventDefault();
     }
})
```

Comment: does exist option to take every inserted char to input and check if he equal to ' '?

Comment: you mean only space not whitespace?

Comment: in the input should prevent insert ' '

Comment: e.preventDefault() or return false, not both

Comment: its like you write 10 times that will also works: e.preventDefault()e.preventDefault()e.preventDefault()e.preventDefault()e.preventDefault()e.preventDefault()e.preventDefault()

Comment: Why not just e.which == ' ' ?

Comment: what is your real problem? the code runs good but you trying to find exceptions for what? this is really annoying. what is the difference between ' ' and 32? i think nothing. what if there is return false? nothing. and please finally accept my answer if good or let me down.

Answer (score 1):

There's a JQuery plugin called AlphaNumeric...

See: http://www.itgroup.com.ph/alphanumeric/

Comment: Can i do the same with validate plugin?

Comment: You can actually do it with just JQuery.  The unpacked version of the plugin is about 80 lines long with just 3 or 4 main functions... pretty simple if you'd like to look at the js and see how Paulo Marinas did it.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to use a regular expression to validate the input.

A regular expression like: `/([a-z]*[A-Z]+)+|([a-z]+[A-Z]*)+/` (only letters upper and lower case)

I don't know exactly how to express this regular expression.

But what you need it is any to test your input value that doesn't allow whitespaces.

Comment: How I doing that with validate jquery plugin

Comment: I hope this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280759/jquery-validate-how-to-add-a-rule-for-regular-expression-validation/709358#709358