# Regex and jQuery, validate input field

Tags: regex, jquery-validate

I have an input field that only can be number and 2 decimals like 23,50. The decimal point have to be an comma , .It has to be exact to decimals even if thay are zeros. I use ths pattern in asp and it seems to be ok, but how can I use it in jquery?

^\d{1,9}(\,\d{2})$

Answer (score 1):

See here:

[jQuery validate: How to add a rule for regular expression validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280759/jquery-validate-how-to-add-a-rule-for-regular-expression-validation)

Comment: OK, but if I want to check on blure or keyup, how kan I use jquery validate then?