# Jquery validation for alphabets

Tags: jquery-validate

I have downloaded jquery validation.js and using it. I need to validate for alphabets in that. For this what i need to do in validation.js

My js is like this,

```
            categoryname: {
            required: true, 
            minlength: 2
        },
messages: { 
            categoryname: "Enter the category name",
```

the above code ask for required field and if field is empty it will show the below message. here i need to validate for only alphabets too.......

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("alphanumericspecial", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || value == value.match(/^[-a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+$/);
        }, "Only letters, Numbers & Space/underscore Allowed.");

    jQuery.validator.addMethod("alpha", function(value, element) {
return this.optional(element) || value == value.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/);
},"Only Characters Allowed.");

    jQuery.validator.addMethod("alphanumeric", function(value, element) {
return this.optional(element) || value == value.match(/^[a-z0-9A-Z#]+$/);
},"Only Characters, Numbers & Hash Allowed.");
```

U can create functions easily like this bro..

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add extra method to validation library, like that:

```
$.validator.addMethod("alpha", function(value,element)
{
   return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z]$/i.test(value); 
}, "Alphabets only");
```

Then you can add it to your validation rules.

Otherwise, you can define generic "regexp" rule, as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280759/jquery-validate-how-to-add-a-rule-for-regular-expression-validation/709358#709358)