# jQuery Validate Plugin: check for alphanum values?

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

anyone ever worked with the jQuery Validate Plugin.

I have like the following function.

```
$("#registrationForm").validate({
        rules: {
            'user[login]': {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6,
                maxlength: 20
            },
            'user[email]': {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
```

I want to check the `user[login]` input for `[0-9a-zA-Z-_]` !

Any idea how to do so? Only alphanum -_ should be allowed.

Comment: This question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280759/jquery-validate-how-to-add-a-rule-for-regular-expression-validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Wow**, sorry: forgot that `regexp` is a custom method I've added in my own code!

Try this:

```
$.validator.addMethod("regexp", function(value, element, pattern) {
    return this.optional(element) || pattern.test(value);
}, "Field contains invalid characters.");
```

And then:

```
$("#my-form").validate({
    rules: {
        "my-field": {
            required: true,
            regexp: /^[0-9a-zA-Z_]*$/
        }
    }
});
```

[Take a look here.](http://jsfiddle.net/K6vdQ/2/)

**Original (wrong) answer:**

<strike>I'm pretty sure you just need to add this:</strike>

```
regexp: /^[0-9a-zA-Z-_]*$/
```

Comment: thank you! however doesn't work: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined` As soon as i type the 7th letter this error gets thrown.

Comment: this is the documentation of the plugin. couldn't find anything: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: thanks for the regexp! I needed to extend the plugin like J.Steen wrote in the comment.