# Form Validation Jquery Regular expression

Tags: jquery, validation

this is my Script :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.validator.addMethod(
        "regex",
        function (value, element, regexp) {
            var re = new RegExp(regexp);
            return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
        },
        "Matricule Invalide"
);
            $("form").validate({
                rules: {
                    idv: { required: true, regex: "/^(\d{3})TN(\d{4})$/" },
                    dd: { required: true },
                    df: { required: true },
                    remise: { required: true, range: [0, 100] }
                },
                messages: {
                  idv: { required:"champs requis", regex: "Matricule Invalide"},
                  dd: "champs requis",
                  df: "champs requis",
                  remise : { required: "champs requis",
                             range: "Valeur doit entre entre 0 et 100"}
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The IDV field has to be like this way "111TN000" or "222TN0123" in other ways it's regular expression: `Number of 3 digets +TN+ Number of Four digets`. I have created my regular expression `"/^(\d{3})TN(\d{4})$/"`, but the probleme here that when i put `Valide IDV` My Jquery Function show me always `Matricule Invalide`, This same Regulare expression works at Java and ASP.net. 
I think i'm missing something very simple here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using the jQuery validate regex plugin, as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280759/jquery-validate-how-to-add-a-rule-for-regular-expression-validation), you need to remove the leading/trailing slashes and escape the other slashes in your regex:

```
idv: { required: true, regex: "^(\\d{3})TN(\\d{4})$" }
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HnrGY/)

---

Alternatively, you can turn it into a regex object by removing the quotes around it:

```
idv: { required: true, regex: /^(\d{3})TN(\d{4})$/ }
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HnrGY/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you must delete slashes

```
"^(\d{3})TN(\d{4})$"
```

Comment: Same probleme `Matricule invalide`