# How to do number validation with jquery.validate.js?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, validation

I'm using the [jQuery Validate plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) and want to validate an input field using a fixed amount of numbers with a dash in the middle like so: **XXXXXX-XXXX**. I know how to validate numbers but how can I get the plugin to validate this specific format?!

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a regex. Add a custom validator method as [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280759/jquery-validate-how-to-add-a-rule-for-regular-expression-validation):

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    "regex",
    function(value, element, regexp) {
        var re = new RegExp(regexp);
        return re.test(value);
    },
    "Please check your input."
);
```

And then attach it to the input element that you need to validate:

```
$('#id_of_textbox').rules('add', { regex: '^[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{4}$' })
```

or if you are using it with the form:

```
$('#id_of_form').validate({
    rules: {
        name_of_textbox: {
            regex: '^[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{4}$'
        }
    },
    messages: {
        name_of_textbox: {
            regex: 'Please provide a valid input for this field'
        }
    }
});
```

And here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/66QtT/).

Comment: Good answer and well done going out of your way to do an example

Answer (score 1):

You can do Regest with Javascript as basic as that.. same way you can include the regest with jquery plugin as well.