# Full year validation jQuery datepicker dpDate

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using jQuery datepicker and the dpDate plugin to validate the input.
I want the validation to fail when the year is not in 4 digits.
(when someone enters the date using keyboard this seems to be possible).

dpDate returns true on 80-01-01 (Jan 1, 1980).
But it should users force to write it like 1980-01-01

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the plugin is `jquery.ui.datepicker.validation.js`; `dpDate` is one of the new validation methods it defines. For the benefit of other readers, it can be found at:

http://keith-wood.name/uiDatepickerValidation.html

This method simply uses `$.datepicker.parseDate` using the dateFormat you specified -- if it doesn't report an error, it considers the input valid. Since `parseDate` allows abbreviated years, so does the plugin.

Instead, you can use the regular expression `/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/`; this question shows how to add a `regex` validation method. If you combine it with the `dpDate` method, it will check that it has 4 digits and that it's also a valid date.

[jQuery validate: How to add a rule for regular expression validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280759/jquery-validate-how-to-add-a-rule-for-regular-expression-validation)

What I do in my application is a little different. I simply don't allow the user to edit the date field directly. I set it `readonly`, but this still allows the datepicker to fill it in. Since the datepicker always enters 4-digit years, I don't have to worry much about validating it.