# Regex not working in jquery validation plugin

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I am using below code

```
$(function() {
    $("#myForm").validate({
        rules: {
            experience: {
                required: true,
                regex: '^[0-9]$'
            }
        },
        messages: {
            experience: {
                required: "Please provide experience",
                regex: "Provide a valid input for experience"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

But the above code is not taking 2 or 22 as valid input? What I am doing wrong? Help required...

Comment: try `regex: '^[0-9]+$'`

Comment: The plugin doc site seems down but I suspect the plugin needs a regex, not a string. Can you try with a regex literal : `regex: /^[0-9]$/` ? EDIT : found the source code, shouldn't matter.

Comment: Can you build a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so that we can reproduce your problem ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this regex instead:

```
^[0-9]+$
```

Then put it in the code:

```
$(function() {
   $.validator.addMethod("regex", function(value, element, regexpr) {          
     return regexpr.test(value);
   }, "Please enter a valid pasword.");    

   $("#myForm").validate({
       rules: {
           experience: {
               required: true,
               regex: /^[0-9]+$/
           }
       }
   });
});
```

Here is a working demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/4PuJL/1/

Comment: How would you explain the fact that 2 wasn't seen as valid ?

Comment: @dystroy As you suspected in your comment , the plugin expect a regular expression not a string.

Comment: @dystroy check the demo in my answer.

Comment: Well my problem is regex, and obviously I have one method already added for regex. Now it is working...thanks

Answer (score 4):

There is no regex method in validate jquery:
You have to create of your regex method of your own

You need to use `addmethod`

```
$.validator.addMethod("regx", function(value, element, regexpr) {          
    return regexpr.test(value);
}, "Provide a valid input for experience.");
```

Your function here:

```
$(function() {
    $("#myForm").validate({
        rules: {
            experience: {
                required: true,
                regex: /^[0-9]$/
            }
        },
        messages: {
            experience: {
                required: "Please provide experience",

            }
        }
    });
});
```

**[add regex in Jquery.validate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785529/add-regex-to-jquery-validate)**

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my email field had it's own regex pattern data like

```
<input id="email" name="email" data-val-regex-pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$">
```

which conflicted with the pattern I injected for JQuery Validation plugin. I just removed this data- attribute and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

You can use 'pattern' keyword instead of 'regex' in .validate() form of jQuery. Below is sample code :

```
$('#registerForm').validate({
    rules: {
        "customer[is_seller]": {
            required:true
        },
        "customer[fname]": {
            required:true,
            pattern:/^[A-Za-z]+$/
        },
        "customer[lname]": {
            required:true,
            pattern:/^[A-Za-z\s]+$/
        },
        "customer[email]": {
            required:true,
            email:true
        },
        "customer[password]": {
            required:true
        }
    },
    messages:{
        "customer[is_seller]": {
            required:"Please select Your category"
        },
        "customer[fname]": {
            required:"Please enter first name.",
            pattern:"Special characters not allowed"
        },
        "customer[lname]": {
            required:"Please enter last name."
            pattern:"Special characters not allowed"
        },
        "customer[email]":{
            required:"Email Id is required",
            email:"Please enter a valid email."
        },
        "customer[password]":{
            required:"Password is required"
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined.  Exception occurred when checking element zipcode, check the 'pattern' method.