# How can i add the regular expressions for form validation(name,email,phone number

Tags: jquery

Here is my jquery code for form validation:
I am facing issue with below code like even replace the expression with the field the functionality is not working

below is the code:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".submit").click(function() {
    $("#myForm").validate({
      rules: {

        'name': {    // this is value of the name attribute of your field
          required: true,
        },

       'email':{
           required:true,
          // regex: 'regex for email field goes here'
        } ,
      'phone':{
        required: true,
      }
      },
      messages: {
        'name': {
          required: "Name is required"
        },

        'email': {
          required: "Email is required",
          //regex: 'Error response for regex fail goes here'
        },
         'phone':{
        required: "phone number is required",
      }
  }

    });


  });

});
```

Now how can i add the regex expressions for email phone number,name field.

i am new to jquery can anyone help me adding the expression?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex not working in jquery validation plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20946751/regex-not-working-in-jquery-validation-plugin)

Answer (score 1):

From [add regex to jquery.validate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785529/add-regex-to-jquery-validate),

```
$.validator.addMethod("regx", function(value, element, regexpr) {          
    return regexpr.test(value);
}, "Enter an valid email.");
$("#myForm").validate({
    rules: {
        'email':{
            required:true,
            regx: /[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+/
        }
    },
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For Example,

```
$("#myForm").validate({
   rules: {
       experience: {
           required: true,
           regex: /^[0-9]+$/
       }
   }
 });
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4PuJL/1/)