# Having trouble with regular expression in javascript not validating when it should

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Hello i am trying to validate some form input where the format needs to be.

GBR (Exactly) followed by [1-9] for 1 digit then [0-9] for 2 digits and then nothing else.

I am using it inside some jquery.

```
            jQuery(function(){
            jQuery("#P3_P_CODE").validate({
                expression: "if (VAL.match(/^\w[GBR]{1,3}[1-9]{1,1}\d[0-9]{1,1}$/)) return true; else return false;",
                message: "Should be a valid Project format"
            });
        });
```

Meaning that

```
/^\w[GBR]{1,3}[1-9]{1,1}\d[0-9]{1,1}$/
```

is my regular expression.

The problem that i am having is that no matter what i type into the input box i am still presented with an error message meaning that my regular expression must be incorrect.

I have tried several different combinations in my REGEXP to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: this page will probably help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280759/jquery-validate-how-to-add-a-rule-for-regular-expression-validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/^GBR[1-9]\d\d$/
```

`[GBR]` means one of those characters.

Comment: I see what you mean :) i have added your changes but it is still not accepting a value of GBR101 for instance.

Comment: The regular expression works: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZMXGe/). What plugin are you using for validation?

Comment: I am Using

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" />


    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/jquery.validate.js" />

Comment: According to the documentation there is no "expression" option.

Comment: Ahhh briliant, so obviously no matter what i entered mine would of returned false, my mistake i'll see if i can find a library that includes an expression option.