# Validate form in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, action

i got a problem with my Order form. I need to validate some of the fields, checkboxs, dropdown list, and the quantity of the products. So i just started with the checkbox.
It have to looks like: If i check the box, but not specify the quantity of the product, its popup a javascript alert that tell me to specify how much i want to order from that product. And if i dont check the checkbox its start alert me with that. Second, i need to Validate the card number for: Only number and 20 character with - after every 4 digits.
Just done with the checkbox validate but cant even done the quantity validate and the card number, card type validate.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="iso-8859-2">
<title>Order</title>

<script language="javascript">
function validateFunction() {
var fo = document.cardform;
if (!fo.field1.checked && !fo.field2.checked && !fo.field3.checked) {
      alert("Must choose at least one thing to buy");
      return false;
}
return true;
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <h2>
        <strong>
            Order
        </strong>
    </h2>
    <form name="cardform" action="" onsubmit="return validateFunction();">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" size="40px" required> </br>
    Adress: <input type="text" name="adress" size="40px" required> </br>
    Card Type: <select name="card" form="cardform" required>
                    <option value="choose" selected>Please Choose</option>
                    <option value="visa">Visa</option>
                    <option value="americanexpress">American Express</option>
                    <option value="mastercard">Master Card</option>
                    <option value="maestro">Maestro</option>
</select>
    Cardnumber: <input type="number" name="cardnumber" required> </br>
    <table border="1px">
        <tr>
            <td>
            name:
            </td>
            <td>
            price:
            </td>
            <td>
            q:
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="field1">1
            </td>
            <td>
            13
            </td>
            <td>
            <input type="text" name="1q">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="field2">2
            </td>
            <td>
            133
            </td>
            <td>
            <input type="text" name="2q">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="field3">3
            </td>
            <td>
            1337
            </td>
            <td>
            <input type="text" name="3q">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>    
    Comment: </br>
    <textarea name="comments" cols="25" rows="5"> Comment here </textarea> </br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        <input type="reset" value="Reset">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear what you are asking exactly, but it sounds like you are looking for some general advice on form validation.

I would suggest using jQuery and then use [jQuery Validate](http://plugins.jquery.com/validate/).

Check the documentation and lots of examples [here](https://github.com/DiegoLopesLima/Validate#readme).

Basically what it lets you do is to decorate your HTML tags with attributes that tell jQuery Validate how that tag, be it a checkbox or an input field, should be validated.

Comment: Download this Jquery validate, and i have to say its really awesome. Just done with the name, adress, and card type fields. But i dont know how to validate the checkboxes with this. (If a user doesn't check a box, it should become red. If the user check it, but doesn't write value inside Quantity field its also become red. I also need to card number field to can only input numbers and - character.

Comment: For the numbers and characters you can write a regular expression validation. I'm no expert on RegEx, but take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280759/jquery-validate-how-to-add-a-rule-for-regular-expression-validation) SO question for help. I'm not sure what you mean about the checkbox, can you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 0):

In my view " there was some required attribute for fields"  if field are empty it is aborting next level ( i mean  your alert message). try with removing required attribute and write validation for remaining fields using js/jquery. Hope it works .