# JQuery Validation - Check if the textbox has special character

Tags: jquery, asp.net

How can I validate the `textbox Name` does not include '@'?

```
 rules: {
            Name: {
                required: true,

            },
            Email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            Password1: {
                minlength: 6
            },
 }
```

Comment: Validation already implemented by somebody else. I don't want sth like alert box to pop up now.

Comment: Where is your `HTML` and `JavaScript`? What have your tried to do already?

Comment: you want something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280759/jquery-validate-how-to-add-a-rule-for-regular-expression-validation

Comment: very unclear question.. to check for a @ symbol, u can just use indexof.. ` if ( $('#textBoxID').val().indexOf('@') == -1) ){ //no @ symbol 
} `

Comment: Already? Nothing. Just thought how to include this in the validate function: ($('#PName').val().indexOf("@@") != -1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the pattern rule

```
rules: {
    Name: {
        required: true,
        pattern: /^[^@]+$/
    },
    Email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
    },
    Password1: {
        minlength: 6
    },
},
messages: {
    Name: {
        pattern: 'Name should not contain @'
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gdK2P/)

Comment: I just needed to double the '@' as this is razor.