# JQuery validate - pattern rule is not working as well as custom regex method

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I'm using [JQuery Validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin to validate if an input contains any spaces or not (No spaces are allowed).

I've tried `pattern` rule from the `additional-methods.js` file but it doesn't work at all:

```
"fos_user_registration_form[plainPassword][first]": {
    required: true,
    minlength: 6,
    pattern: "/^\S*$/"
},
```

And tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/709358/845371)

```
"fos_user_registration_form[plainPassword][first]": {
    required: true,
    minlength: 6,
    regex: "/^\S*$/"
},
```

Bit still it doesn't fire at all when, for example, I type "*this is test*".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For anyone who faced the same problem. Actually it was a typo from my side.

Simply you'll have to remove the quotations in the regex. Because `RegExp` constructor accepts it without quotations. So it'll be:

```
"fos_user_registration_form[plainPassword][first]": {
    required: true,
    minlength: 6,
    pattern: /^\S*$/
},
```