# Using Regex with JqueryUI Validate

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-ui, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to add a regex validation to my JQueryUI validator following the guidance of [jQuery validate: How to add a rule for regular expression validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280759/jquery-validate-how-to-add-a-rule-for-regular-expression-validation)

```
$.validator.addMethod(
        "regex",
        function(value, element, regexp) {
            var re = new RegExp(regexp);
            return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
        },
        "Please check your input."
);
```

and

```
$("#Textbox").rules("add", { regex: "^[a-zA-Z'.\\s]{1,40}$" })
```

The regex that I would like to include is

```
^(\d+(?:(?: \d+)*\/\d+)?)$
```

Which can be seen at http://regex101.com/r/cB3fQ1/2

When I enter the regex into the jquery, no entries pass.  This is how I entered it

```
$("#Textbox").rules("add", { regex: "^(\d+(?:(?: \d+)*\/\d+)?)$" })
```

Is it because I am wrapping it in a string and some syntac is conflicting?  I am inexperienced at regex and am not sure how to go about trouble shooting this.  Please advise me if you see where my error is.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to double escape the backslashes since you're entering regex as string:

```
$("#Textbox").rules("add", { regex: "^(\\d+(?:(?: \\d+)*\/\\d+)?)$" })
```

OR else use **regex literal**:

```
$("#Textbox").rules("add", { regex: /^(\d+(?:(?: \d+)*\/\d+)?)$/ })
```