# How can I change form validation pattern based on dropdown selection?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, validation, angular5

I'm setting up form validation in the UI for one of our projects.  One of the text boxes needs to have a differing validation `pattern` based on the selection of a previous dropdown.  For example, if the dropdown selection is `name`, the pattern should be:

```
pattern='[a-zA-Z ]+'
```

where as if it is `number`, it should be:

```
pattern='[0-9 ]+`
```

I've setup a function in the component to set up a validation string based on that selection:

```
fields: string[] = [];
validationPattern: string;

private validationType(field: string[]) {
    if (field.includes('number')) {
        this.validationPattern = '[0-9]+';
        return this.validationPattern;
    } else if (field.includes('name')) {
        this.validationPattern = '[a-zA-Z1-9][a-zA-Z0-9 ]+';
        return this.validationPattern;
    }
}
```

And in the HTML, I have the following. setField is a function to actually choose the field;  validationType is what I'm trying to use to create the validation pattern for the input:

```
<div ngbDropdownMenu>
    <button
        *ngFor="let selected of fields"
         class="dropdown-item"
         (click)="setField(selected); validationType(selected)">
         {{ selected }}
    </button>
</div>
```

And here is the input the form validation is on:

```
<input
    type="text"
    id="value"
    name="value"
    placeholder="Value"
    #value1="ngModel"
    pattern=this.validationPattern
    [(ngModel)]="profile.value">
```

I have two issues so far:

1. How can I properly pass either the value of the validationPattern variable or the output of the validationType() function to pattern in the input?  As of right now, it seems to be reading `this.validationPattern` as the actual pattern - that is, the words `this.validationPattern` and not the associated value. No matter if I select name or number, anything I type in is invalid.
2. How can I use validationType() outside of the click? I've been told it is very bad practice to have more than one function associated to a (click), and in this particular case, it should be reserved for setField().

Comment: [this might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280759/jquery-validate-how-to-add-a-rule-for-regular-expression-validation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your questions are valid one -

> 1. Binding `validationPattern` variable

Your code is looking fine however it require small correction to get the value from ts file to html. As of now you are no using bracket `[]` so whatever you will pass it will take as string value. If you want to get some dynamic value you must use brackets.

```
 <input
    type="text"
    id="value"
    name="value"
    placeholder="Value"
    #value1="ngModel"
    [pattern]="validationPattern"  <!-- Get the dynamic value of validationPattern
    [(ngModel)]="profile.value">
```

> 2. How can I validationType() outside of the click ?

Right, calling multiple function within `click` is not good practice however it doesn't impact on the execution. In your case you are calling one function `setField` already. You can leverage this function you can `validationType` inside `setField`.

ex:

### in ts

```
setField(selected){
    this.validationType(selected);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To bind the `pattern` property to `validationPattern`, use [property binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding--property-):

```
[pattern]="validationPattern"
```

As for calling two functions in one event handler, I don't see it as bad practice, especially for a button click event which is not triggered so frequently.