# Dynamically add validator method not working well

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

The `method0`~`method4` work not well.
I add this into validator of jQuery. The wired result shows.
How can I fix it.

```
var conditions = [
    {
        "regexp": ".{8,}",
        "message": ""
    },
    {
        "regexp": "[A-Z]",
        "message": ""
    },
    {
        "regexp": "[0-9]",
        "message": ""
    },
    {
        "regexp": "(.)\\1{3}",
        "message": ""
    },
    {
        "regexp": "[a-z]",
        "message": ""
    }
];

    for (var i in conditions) {
        var methodName = "method" + i;
        pwdRules[methodName] = true;
        pwdMsgs[methodName] = conditions[i].message;

        $.validator.addMethod(
            methodName,
            function(value, element) {
                return value.match(conditions[i].regexp) != null;
            },
            conditions[i].message
        );
    }
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking here? Could just be me, but what are you validating here? Where is 'It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.' coming from? Are we missing some of your code?

Comment: @tmkiernan, the OP is bypassing the warning system.  Instead of writing a better description with more details as prompted, he's filling it up with the SO message, *"It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."*

Comment: As it stands your question needs more of the relevant code and a better description.  Please fix your question.  No idea why you think you need to dynamically write a custom method for each individual condition.   Instead you can pass the condition into the method as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no reason to create multiple versions of the same custom method.  Create one custom method and pass the different parameters into it as `params`.

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    myMethodName,
    function(value, element, params) {
        // one parameter is just passed in as a number or string and accessed directly as params
        // multiple parameters are passed as an array ["first", "second", "etc"]
        // first parameter is params[0]
        // second parameter is params[1], etc.
    },
    "custom message"
);
```

The custom message can be a plain string...

```
"this is my custom message"
```

or a string that dynamically inserts the parameters into the message using the placeholders `{0}`, `{1}`, etc...

```
"your entered value must be at least {0} and less than {1}"
```

or a function that constructs any message you wish...

```
function() {
    var message;
    if (params == "something") {
        message = "my custom message for something";
    } else {
        message = "my default";
    }
    return message;
}
```

---

However, if you simply want to use regex, then there is already a method/rule called `pattern` built into [the `additional-methods.js` file](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/additional-methods.js), which will take regex as the parameter.

See:  [jQuery validate: How to add a rule for regular expression validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/280759/594235)