# jQuery validation multiple equals

Tags: html, jquery, validation

I am using the jQuery validation tool https://jqueryvalidation.org/

And trying to validate a field for the value of either "green", "Green" or "GREEN". Can you add multiple equals values to the rules? Or may be it is better to convert the string to lowercase?

```
 $.validator.addMethod("equals", function(value, element, string) {
 return value === string;
 }, $.validator.format("Please answer the question"));


 $("#contactForm").validate({
   rules: {
      question: {
        required: true,
        equals: "green"  
      } 
    }   
 });
```

Comment: Do you really need multiple equals, or just case-insensitive matching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a validation method that takes an array of values to allow.

```js
$.validator.addMethod("member", function(value, element, array) {
  return array.includes(value);
}, $.validator.format("Please answer the question"));

$("#contactForm").validate({
   rules: {
      question: {
        required: true,
        member: ["green", "GREEN", "Green"]
      } 
    }   
 });
```

Another alternative is to use one of the regexp methods here: [jQuery validate: How to add a rule for regular expression validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280759/jquery-validate-how-to-add-a-rule-for-regular-expression-validation)

Then you can use alternatives in the regexp:

```
regex: /green|Green|GREEN/
```

With a regular expression you can also make it case-insensitive easily:

```
regex: /green/i
```

Comment: I tried this previously 

equals ["green", "GREEN", "Green"]

And it then just accepted none of them?

Comment: A string can never be equal to an array.

Comment: This is the error I get when I try your exact code:

Uncaught TypeError: elements.includes is not a function.  Exception occurred when checking element question, check the 'member' method.

Comment: Sorry, I had the parameters wrong, try it now.