# Why is the JavaScript RegExp.test() method behaving as a toggle?

Tags: javascript, regex

Can anyone explain why the `alert()` in the following JavaScript code is firing?  It appears to be a bug in the `RegExp.test()` method which reverses its previous decision each time you run the method.  I'm using IE7.

I've found a replacement that appears solid, using the `string.search(regex)` method instead.  But, I'm curious whether anyone knows something about this.

```
  var styleHasWidthRegex = /\bwidth\s*\:/ig;
  var styleText = "WIDTH: 350px";
  var result1 = styleHasWidthRegex.test(styleText);
  var result2 = !styleHasWidthRegex.test(styleText);
  if (result1 == result2) {
    alert("This should never happen!");
  }
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Your regex has the global (`g`) flag set. Every time it is executed, it'll update an internal index (the [lastIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/LastIndex) property) specifying where it left off, and begin searching at that point the next time through.

Of course, you don't really want that - you want it to start at the beginning every time. So ditch the `g` flag.

#### See also: [Inconsistent javascript logic behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209732/inconsistent-javascript-logic-behavior)

Comment: Thanks for making sense out of that.

Comment: no problem, John. Took me a while to get it the first time i saw it too!

Comment: ....you're awesome!  Learn something new today :D

Comment: came here to upvote. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, you should be needing a global tag anyways, since in css declarations a property should only be declared once.