# Chrome dev tools regex test returning a different result everytime its called

Tags: javascript, regex

I don't know why but Chrome dev tools regex test returning a different result everytime its called. I have this as the string to be tested:

```
SELECT tbl_school.id AS tbl_school_id, school, tbl_students.id AS tbl_students_id, name, hobby, school_id, course_id FROM tbl_school, tbl_students WHERE tbl_school.id = 's' dd
ORDER BY tbl_school.id ASC
```

The where regex is:

```
var where_regex = /where/ig
```

Here's a screenshot of the results, as you can see its changing everytime its called but I didn't change anything in the string. I'll really appreciate an explanation for this

[image]

Comment: can somebody explain what's the downvote all about?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the JavaScript RegExp.test() method behaving as a toggle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894696/why-is-the-javascript-regexp-test-method-behaving-as-a-toggle)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because of `/g` flag AND the fact that the same regex object is used. Quoting the doc ([**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test))

> As with `exec` (or in combination with it), `test` called multiple times
>   on the same global regular expression instance will advance past the
>   previous match.

Consider this:

```
var r = /w/g;
console.log( r.test('Awa') ); // true
console.log( r.test('Awa') ); // false
console.log( r.test('Awa') ); // true
console.log( r.test('Awa') ); // false

console.log( /w/ig.test('Awa') ); // true
console.log( /w/ig.test('Awa') ); // true
console.log( /w/ig.test('Awa') ); // true
console.log( /w/ig.test('Awa') ); // true
```

In the first group of statements (using the same regex object stored in `r` variable) the second match starts from the place where the first one has finished (i.e., *after* `w`). Note that using `//g.test` after it has failed will reset it - so the match will start from the beginning of that line.

But in the second group of statements each time a new regex object is created, and each of these (obviously) stores the position of the last match separately. Hence, it's four `true` there.

The bottom line is that it's quite... weird to use `/g` with `test` method - unless you want the pattern to walk over the string, of course. Remember, `test` returns `true` or `false` (and doesn't capture anything), so in normal cases enabling the regex global mode is redundant, to say the least.

Comment: So is there a way to reuse a regex object for repeatedly calling test? is there a method/property that would trigger "reset"? My use case: for each string in an array, check if it only consists of whitespace characters (can be multiline).

Comment: Not sure that I got it right, but how about simply checking each string for `/\S/` instead - without global flag?

Comment: Sorry, it was me, I didn't realize at first that I just need to get rid of the global flag. Thanks!