# Combine Search and checkbox filters in Vue js

Tags: search, vuejs2, computed-properties

I have to filter a list using a Search input field and als some Checkboxes (filter on a category).

I have both functionalities working independently.

**The Search field**

```
computed: {
    getfilteredData() {
      return this.experiences.filter(experience =>
        experience.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||
          experience.category.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()
        )
      )
    }
  },
```

**The Checkboxes**

```
computed: {
    getfilteredData() {
      if (!this.checkedCategories.length)
        return this.experiences

        return this.experiences.filter(experience => 
          this.checkedCategories.includes(experience.category))
    }
  },
```

How do I combine those filters? So they are working simultaneously?

Comment: using both filters as` .filter(...firstFilter).filter(...secondFilter)` will result in both filters working as an AND

Answer (score 1):

combining both filters in succession will filter both as an AND statement

```js
getfilteredData() {
    return this.experiences.filter(experience =>
        experience.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||
            experience.category.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()
        )
    ).filter(experience => 
        // if there are no checkboxes checked. all values will pass otherwise the category must be included
        !this.checkedCategories.length || this.checkedCategories.includes(experience.category)
    )
}
```

otherwise, you could combine them in one filter with `(firstCondition || secondCondition)` with the same logic you use above.

I saw your other question that got closed [Write my Javascript more cleaner in my Vue js search functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62389363/write-my-javascript-more-cleaner-in-my-vue-js-search-functionality)
where I think you could rewrite your function like this

```js
experience => {
    let reg = new RegExp(this.search, 'gi')
    return reg.test(`${experience.name} ${experience.category}`)
}
```

using `g` means that your string can be in any position, but you must reconstruct your regex on each test otherwise you can end up with issues found here

[Why am I seeing inconsistent JavaScript logic behavior looping with an alert() vs. without it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209732/why-am-i-seeing-inconsistent-javascript-logic-behavior-looping-with-an-alert-v)

using `i` means it will ignore casing so you don't need to worry about using `toLowerCase()`

thus your filter can be written like this in one statement

```js
experience => {
    let reg = new RegExp(this.search, 'gi')

    // search input matches AND the checkbox matches
    return reg.test(`${experience.name} ${experience.category}`) && (!this.checkedCategories.length || this.checkedCategories.includes(experience.category))

    // search input matches OR the checkbox matches
    //return reg.test(`${experience.name} ${experience.category}`) || (!this.checkedCategories.length || this.checkedCategories.includes(experience.category))
}
```